# how to invoke scala method in play framework view page

Tags: scala, playframework

I'am in new in play framework and i have a doubt about these questions any experts in play framework shouldanswer these questions

```
In play framework the scala methods are how to invoke inside view ?

these method will create inside the application or model in the project
```

with regards,     Prasanth AR

```
my language is not good I know, and sorry about that
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To define a method inside Twirl's template add `@` before the name and code block

```
@incr(number: Int) = @{ @number + 1 }
```

To invoke scala method or variable add `@` symbol before the name

```
<div>@incr(10)</div>
```

Will return and print `11` in `div` block